# Composer, set minimum download stability

Tags: windows, composer-php, command-line-interface

i am pretty new with composer and i am having a problem with a download.
I install composer and afterwards i want to install a proyect in beta state trough this command:

```
 composer require google/apiclient:^2.0.0@RC
```

(This would download the google api client libraries with all their dependencies configurated).

I receive an error telling me that the package is not available in a stable-enough version for my minimum stability settings.

I have read a lot comments from people regarding this issue, but it always involves a composer.JSON file in a local project (not an external download from step 1).

My question is, how could i dowload that project? I would first have to set the minimum stability of composer to "dev" instead of "stable", but how can i do this?

This is what I get:
[image]

Comment: Can you describe a bit more what you currently have? Are you starting from scratch? What is inside `composer.json`? Can you post the full error message (it should give details about which versions have been tried)? You should be able to edit your question to add this info.

Comment: Can you also post the result of `php -v` to see which version of PHP you are running. The minimum required is PHP 5.4 for this library.

Comment: I am currently starting from scratch. I am doing something related to youtube data api v3, and for it i need google client api libraries. I do not remember exactly the php version which i am using, but i am pretty sure it was 5.4+. That download gets you all, (libraries + composer.json). I did tried using composer "require google/apiclient:1.6.0" command to get the last stable version, and all was OK.

Comment: Edit: Just to clarify: "composer require" command does NOT requiere a composer.json (if it is an stable version), it GIVES you a composer.json and composer.lock (apart from all the libraries). So i repit, i do not start with a composer.json. Question is, how to make able to "composer require" to get RC estability libraries?

Comment: I wouldn't say it is solved because running the command you gave in a completely empty directory worked for me (running PHP 7). By setting "minimum-stability" to dev, you allow unstable software package to be installed. This will wreck your software at some point.

Comment: The only PHP version giving me an error like the one you mentioned is PHP 5.3. I can call the command line with the latest 5.4.46 just fine.

Comment: My php version is 5.4.12 between. That was actually the point, how to download dev stability libraries if the command "require" does not allow you to download libraries with low stability. Perhaps you are allowed to do it, but i was not, and the solution i provided solved my issue. I do not understand why did you delete the answer.

Comment: The command works fine for me, and it is supposed to work fine for you too. Let's find out why it doesn't: Could you create a new, empty directory, go into it, and call that "require" command, and post the output, please. -- The reason for editing your answer is that answers belong into the answer section, and you should be able to answer yourself. Answers do not belong into the questions text.

Comment: Sure. Sorry, i did not notice there was a place to post the answer (i saw the answer in the principal post in another thread):

Comment: I have just tried to do it with another Php version (5.5.12) and still the same error. This is what i get: [Console image](http://i.imgsafe.org/33244c2.png).  I will post the answer in the correct place.

Comment: Oh, you are using the Windows command line. That's an important information. The `@` sign has special meaning on the command line in Windows, so the package name and version has to be inside double quotes to work. Otherwise everything including the `@` is ignored, and the command would look like you want to install the stable version. I posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLUTION: I finally solved it this way:

First you need to create an empty `composer.json` file wherever you want.

Afterwards you do something like this (or literally this, in my case):

```
{

"name": "Your title",

"minimum-stability": "dev",

"require": 

{
       "google/apiclient": "2.0.*"
    }
}
```

Afterwards you go to the directory with this file in the cmd (windows console) and type "`composer install`".

This will solve the problem and install all the libraries with its dependencies. It is not the same as setting the minimum stability to "dev" for all libraries, but it will solve the problem for specific packages.

Comment: The problem was created by the windows command line treating the "@RC" as non-existing, so it tried to install the ^2.0.0 stable release, which currently does not exist. The error message was somehow correct to lower the stability setting, but on the one hand correctly passing it on the command line works, alternatively editing the `composer.json` with the version and then running `composer update` would work. Setting "minimum-stability" to "RC" would also work, but will affect ALL packages. Setting it to "dev" should really be treated as a last resort.

Answer (score 3):

The windows command shell requires to enclose the package and version into double quotes (and it isn't a bad idea in Linux as well):

```
Doesn't work in Windows:
composer require google/apiclient:^2.0.0@RC 

Does work:
composer require "google/apiclient:^2.0.0@RC"
```

Please don't set "minimum-stability" to "dev", because this is a global setting and will instantly install development versions that you probably don't want, because they are no final release and may be unstable. This would be true for ALL packages you require, and their dependencies.